# how to query folders in google drive use objective c?

Tags: google-drive-api

I wanna get the folder's id use folder's title in google drive,so I use objc to execute a query.Like these codes:

```
-(void)startrestore
{
    GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
    query.q = @"title='hello' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
    [service executeQuery:query
        completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveFileList *files,
                            NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"4");
            if (error == nil) {
                NSString *array = files.JSONString;
                NSLog(@"%@",array);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
            }
        }];
}
```

But the response is:

```
{
  "kind" : "drive#fileList",
  "etag" : "\"KYLl3b7q6n8KW2kbVvK9NFUdVkc\/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8\""
}
```

If I change the code like this:

```
query.q = @"title='picture.jpg' and mimeType='image/jpeg'";
```

the response is:

```
{
  "kind" : "drive#fileList",
  "etag" : "\"KYLl3b7q6n8KW2kbVvK9NFUdVkc\/vyGp6PvFo4RvsFtPoIWeCReyIC8\""
}
```

Why?

Comment: That response just means that no files matched your search criteria. I suggest using the "try it now" feature of the web page to experiment

Comment: There is a folder named 'hello' and a picture named 'picture.jpg',and I use the try it now,but I get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I am foolish,I fixed it up,we should use the scope kGTLAuthScopeDrive rather than the scope
kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile.